# Query results are not sorted using ldap.js framework in node.js server

Tags: node.js, sorting, ldap, ldapjs

I tried to query 'LDAP server users' with my **node.js** server. 
here is my codes what i tried with '**Ldapjs** framework'

```
function ldapQuery_Users(){
var opts = {
    filter: '(uid=*)',
    scope: 'sub'
// attributes: ['dn', 'sn', 'cn', 'phone', 'fax', 'mail']
};

client.search('dc=mirageworks, dc=kr', opts, function(err, res) {
    assert.ifError(err);
    res.on('searchEntry', function(entry) {
      console.log(entry.attributes.toString());
    });
    res.on('searchReference', function(referral) {
      console.log('referral: ' + referral.uris.join());
    });
    res.on('error', function(err) {
      console.error('error: ' + err.message);
    });
    res.on('end', function(result) {
      //console.log('ldapLogin status: ' + ((result.status == 0) ? "success" :  result.status));
    });
 });
}
```

And the result is like this.

[image]

When I set attributes items in opts array, the results are sorted as what I set.
But with no attributes, no sorted items.

The first user's result is starting **"type" : "uid"**. these items seem ascending sorted.
But second and thrid are decending sorted. these are starting with **"type":"telephoneNumber"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LDAP protocol specifically states the result order is unspecified.

LDAP server Implementations MAY return entries or attributes within a specific order, however there is no standard.

Using the [LDAP Control Extension for Server Side Sorting of Search Results](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2891) is a possibility for returning the entries within a specified order.

There is no "Standard" for sorting Attribute Results and they will need to be sorted "client-side"